# Sorting HashMap<String, String> with integers as Strings

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

I'm trying to sort my HasMap ArrayList so my listview is sorted by values but I'm not getting it.
Basically I have several keys and one of them is "type" which holds values like `"1", "4", "3",....`

I want to order the list by this key "type" but I'm getting `"1", "11", "2"` instead of `"1", "2", "11"`...

I'm trying this code to sort it:

```
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>() {
public int compare(HashMap<String, 
String> mapping1,HashMap<String, String> mapping2) {
return mapping1.get("type").compareTo(mapping2.get("type"));
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are you using a `String` for the key, when you're using it purely to store `ints`?

Comment: There's more keys in there that aren't ints. When I try to change that key to int I get an error on my map.put(key,value)

Comment: In that case, beware of NumberFormatException that will get thrown by your accepted answer - you'll need to expand this logic to accommodate your valid String keys. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your type is a `String` and thats why you are getting `"1", "11", "2"`. Convert that string to integer (Integer.valueOf()) and then compare.

change the following

```
mapping1.get("type").compareTo(mapping2.get("type"));
```

to

```
 Integer.valueOf(mapping1.get("type")).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(mapping2.get("type")));
```

Note: I did not compile the above code.

Answer (score 1):

The *data-type* of "type" seems to be `String`. Hence the sorting `"1", "11", "2"` seems **correct**. Change the *data-type* of "type" to `Integer`

OR

in `compare` method compare `Integer.parseInt` values of the "type"

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to handle non-integer values in your comparator, if, as you mentioned above, you expect to have a mixture of `String` and `Integer` keys.

```
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>() {
    public int compare(HashMap<String, String> mapping1,
                       HashMap<String, String> mapping2) {
        String valueOne = mapping1.get("type");
        String valueTwo = mapping2.get("type");
        try {
            return Integer.valueOf(valueOne).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(valueTwo));
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            return valueOne.compareTo(valueTwo);
        }
    }
});
```

(Otherwise, the key value should be changed to `Integer` to avoid mistakes by other developers.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below..

Change parameter as per your need..

```
Set<Entry<String, Integer>> set = map.entrySet();
        List<Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>(set);
        Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>()
        {
            public int compare( Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2 )
            {
                return (o2.getValue()).compareTo( o1.getValue() );
            }
        } );
        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry:list){
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" ==== "+entry.getValue());
        }
```